# Preventing blade php function from encoding symbols

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, encoding, laravel-blade

I have a route calls in my code to show an image inside a folder that has a couple subfolder based on categories. This is my route call in datatable to show the image :

```
<img id="pic" src="{{url('api/image',['folder/subfolder1',$data->image]}}" style="width:150;height:150"/>
```

i got an error cause the '/' on 'folder/subfolder1' change into '%2f', how do you prevent this from happening??
i expect the api to return link that looks something like this :

```
<img id="pic" src="localhost:8000/api/image/folder/subfolder1/image.jpg/>
```

instead i got :

```
<img id="pic" src="localhost:8000/api/image/folder%2fsubfolder1/image.jpg/>
```

the getImage controller looks something like this:

```
public function getImage($foldername,$filename){
$path = ['UPLOAD_PATH'].'/image';
return Image::make($path.'/'.$foldername'/'.$filename)->response();
}
```

here's the route api :

```
Route::get('image/{foldername}/{filename}','getImageController@getImage')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect this result below

```
<img id="pic" src="localhost:8000/api/image/folder/subfolder1/image.jpg" />
```

Then you may try this below.

```
<img id="pic" src="{{url('api/image/folder/subfolder1/' . $data->image }}" style="width:150;height:150"/>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: my route api look like this sir, 

`Route::get('image/{foldername}/{filename}','getImageController@getImage')`. i think something is wrong with how the controller handle the links, it works fine with directories thats doesnt have any subfolders

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape your own internal route.  Use blade's non-escaped {!! !!}} instead:

```
<img id="pic" src="{!! url('api/image',['folder/subfolder1',$data->image] !!}" ... />
```

I would also perhaps make the routing a little more simple - why not just use the `api/image/folder/subfolder1/'.$data->image` or similar?

Comment: i still got the same result

Comment: Even if you use the different route that I put at the end of the answer?  Should have worked fine.

Comment: The routes is supposed to handle images in a folder without any subfolders, it works fine for `url('api/image',['foldername',$data->image])`. there's only 1 folder that have 3 subfolder in it, thats where this problem appeared

Comment: btw @Jesus solution works, the link are correct, %2f is gone, but the images still doesnt load, it might have something to do with the controller

Answer (score 1):

You may use route instead of url when sending to request url will be encoded as special char.

try using this code :

```
<img id="pic" src="{{route('public/image/')}$data->image}}">
```